# How to write mobx reaction to successful data fetch?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I need to have two successive data fetches. I need to fetch devices that contain a list of data feeds, and then I need to fetch the contents of the data feeds on the device that is active in the UI. I've figured out that I need a reaction somewhere somehow, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Right now I have:

### Device UI component snippet

```
componentDidMount() {
    DeviceStore.setActiveDevice(this.props.routeParams.deviceName)
}
```

### MobX Store

```
class DeviceStore {
    userStore
    transportLayer
    @observable devices = []
    @observable isLoadingDevices = true
    @observable activeDevice = null

    constructor(transportLayer, userStore) {
        this.transportLayer = transportLayer
        this.userStore = userStore
        this.loadDevices()
    }

    loadDevices() {
        this.isLoadingDevices = true
        this.transportLayer.fetchDevices(this.userStore.username)
        .then(devices => {
            devices.forEach(json => this.updateDeviceFromServer(json))
            this.isLoadingDevices = false
        })
    }

    loadFeeds(deviceName) {
        let device =
            this.devices.find(device => device.name === deviceName)
        this.transportLayer.fetchFeeds(this.userStore.username, device)
        .then(feeds => {
            console.log(feeds)
            this.updateDeviceFromServer({
                name: deviceName,
                feeds: feeds
            })
        })
    }

    updateDeviceFromServer(json) {
        let device =
            this.devices.find(device => device.name === json.name)
        if (!device) {
            device = new Device(this, json)
            this.devices.push(device)
        } else {
            device.updateFromJson(json)
        }
    }

    setActiveDevice(deviceName) {
        this.activeDevice = deviceName
        this.loadFeeds(deviceName)
    }
}
```

I know I need to react to isLoadingDevices being false, and I need to fire off setActiveDevice with the correct deviceName when that reaction occurs, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Note that you probably can express `activeDevice` as computed value based on the data you have loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to call `setActiveDevice` when the observable `isLoadingDevices` is false.
You can use reaction, as you stated, just import it from 'mobx', and use it inside the constructor:

```
constructor() {
    reaction(
        // The callback will run only on change 
        // of observables described in this function
        () => this.isLoadingDevices,
        // The callback, to be called each time the above expression changes
        () => {
            if (!this.isLoadingDevices) {
                this.setActiveDevice(/* Params */)
            }
        }
    )
}
```